# How to correctly search and replace in files?

Tags: php, mysql, search, replace

So I have task that requires me to replace a single word in a few php files due to an update issue *(long story)* .

The name appears in multiple formats eg. NAME name *name* name/ etc.

Whenever I try to replace the name in the correct case, the file doesn't appear to work any longer. It doesn't make any sense the files themselves shouldn't break based on how I perceive the code. The only other solution I can see is to manually do it, which I'd rather not.

I'm using visual studio and the app has some simple connects to Mysql.

Any ideas or tips?

Comment: When you say a single word, is this word part of your PHP code, or just contained in a string or HTML? Are you using a refactor tool or just find/replace?

Comment: Sublime Text allows to search (and replace) by string/regex in any file within a given folder. This could be useful. See: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html

Comment: So the word is actual part of our domain name which needs to be changed eg. $Imageone now needs to be $imagex but its part of the PHP code functions amongst html/css/js . And only using search and replace. And I believe I would probably get similar results with Sublime .